# How to choose a specific word from a page by taking double-clicked and store it into a variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom

For example:

**HTML**

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function chooseAWordFromPage(e){
  const words = e.target.innerText
  //I get stuck here. Please help me
}

document.body.addEventListener('dblclick',chooseAWordFromPage)
```

I am trying to get one word inside the element by double click this word on page in brower. For example: "Hello World". How can I get "Hello" by clicking on page and assign it to a variable?

**Any libraries are not allowed, such as jQuery.**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Your code will get the full text inside the element; what are you trying to isolate from that?

Comment: I am trying to get one word inside the element by double click this word on page in brower. For example: "Hello World". How can I get "Hello" by clicking on page and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 2):

try (after run snippet double click on "Hello World")

```js
function chooseAWordFromPage(e){
  const w = ''+window.getSelection();
  console.log(w);
}

document.body.addEventListener('dblclick',chooseAWordFromPage)
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: I am trying to get the word from clicking that word on the page, and the clicked word is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an XY problem (you're asking how to implement your solution, rather than explaining your problem). If you want to get specifically the word that was double-clicked, you shouldn't be doing this with innerText; innerText just gives the full text and there's no way to determine which part of that text was clicked.

When you double-click a word on a page, it's normally selected, so what you really want to do here is get the selected text on the page, not try to parse it from the clicked element:

```
function chooseAWordFromPage(){
    const word = window.getSelection().toString();
}

document.body.addEventListener('dblclick',chooseAWordFromPage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless each word is surrounded by `<span>` tags, there's no way you could separate the words out into a discrete DOM node. Kamil's `words.split(" ")` solution would get you started, but there's nothing else for the `click` event to attach to.